# move_base: failed to create TrajectoryPlannerROS?

Tags: navigation, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

I keep getting the following error message while trying to follow the navigation robot setup tutorial:

> Failed to create the base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create class of type base_local_planner::TrajectoryPlannerROS

> [MoveBase-10] process has died [pid 4134, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/move_base/bin/move_base __name:=MoveBase __log:=/home/hendrik/.ros/log/a34a5e18-f55d-11e2-9197-0022fb1ea482/MoveBase-10.log].
> log file: /home/hendrik/.ros/log/a34a5e18-f55d-11e2-9197-0022fb1ea482/MoveBase-10*.log

It has worked for a while. I don't know what I've done wrong to end up with this. Whatever information you need in order to help me figure out the cause of this problem I'll happily provide if I can.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72013/move_base:-failed-to-create-trajectoryplannerros?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got things working again...

```
bash# apt-get update
...
bash# apt-get upgrade
...
```

and restarting `roscore`, `rviz` and my stack solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2013-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0